# Подмена источника трафика для метрики

Tags: яндекс-метрика

Собственно вопрос, можно ли подменить источник трафика для метрики. 
Допустим есть сайт "А" с него будут осуществляться переходы на сайт "Б" на сайте "Б" стоит метрика, соответственно она будет показывать что переходы на сайт "Б" были с сайта "А" можно ли подменить источник, что бы в метрике отображалось что переход на сайт "Б" был не с сайта "А" а с сайта скажем "С" ? Спасибо за любой совет.

Comment: Скорее всего нужно подменять заголовок `Referer`, но я могу ошибаться. Да и в Яндексе ребята не тупые работают, может в принципе не прокатить...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поскольку многие коммерческие решения базируются на метрике, то это не будет так просто. Точнее - можно - это все же header, но действительно - в яндексе менее специалисты, чем кто что сделать попытается?

> > Отвечает Леонид Румянцев, экс-топ Seopult, привлеченный эксперт ФРИИ по трафику
>
> **Если бы подменить реферер домена было так легко** — любое агентство
> контекстной рекламы озолотилось бы, выдавая ботов за клики с «Яндекс.
> Директ».
> ...
>
> История **про подделку реферера звучит двойне странно**, с учетом того,
> что в конце 2014 года Chrome, а в след за ним и многие другие
> браузеры, **начали резать реферер** и **перестали передавать источник
> перехода на сайт**.
> ...